# Convert (screenshot captured) image to base 64 without saving to png/jpeg in python

Tags: python

I saw a lot of q&a about converting images to base 64 string from image, all of them involving saving the image physically on pc.
What I want is convert the image to base 64 string without the need to save the image physically.

How can I do it with `pyscreenshot` or `ImageGrab`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
buffer = io.BytesIO()

im=ImageGrab.grab()
im.save(buffer, format='PNG')
im.close()

b64_str = base64.b64encode(buffer.getvalue())
```